# MySQL matching longest prefix in joined tables

Tags: mysql, join, prefix

We have 2 tables, "**callsdb**" holding phone call logs and "**regionsdb**" holding region related prefixes.
What we need to do is generate a joined list matching "**callsdb.destination_number**" with the **LONGEST** prefix of "**regionsdb.country_prefix**".

NOTES:

1) Phone numbers in "callsdb" **may or may not** have a "1001" prefix.

2) Phone numbers in "callsdb" have an extra "00" prefix before country prefix.

We tried the following query but it has extremely poor performance.
Is there a faster way to achieve this?

```
SELECT 
    uid, call_date, destination, name, country_prefix, duration, unit_cost 
FROM 
    callsdb.calls 
INNER JOIN 
    regionsdb.regions 
ON 
(
    (
        (calls.destination_number LIKE CONCAT('100100', regions.country_prefix, '%')) 
        AND 
        (
            LENGTH(regions.country_prefix) = 
            (
                SELECT MAX(LENGTH(regions.country_prefix))
                FROM regionsdb.regions
                WHERE calls.destination_number LIKE CONCAT('100100', regions.country_prefix, '%')
            )
        )
    )
    OR  
    (
        (calls.destination_number LIKE CONCAT('00', regions.country_prefix, '%')) 
        AND 
        (
            LENGTH(regions.country_prefix) = 
            (
                SELECT MAX(LENGTH(regions.country_prefix))
                FROM regionsdb.regions
                WHERE calls.destination_number LIKE CONCAT('00',regions.country_prefix, '%')
            )
        )
    )
)
ORDER BY call_date DESC;
```

**EDIT:**

Execution time reduced by altering the "ON" part of the query. But it is still TOO SLOW!

```
ON 
(
    (
        (IF(calls.destination_number LIKE '1001%', SUBSTRING(calls.destination_number, 5), calls.destination_number) LIKE CONCAT('00', regions.country_prefix, '%')) 
        AND 
        (
            LENGTH(regions.country_prefix) = 
            (
                SELECT MAX(LENGTH(regions.country_prefix))
                FROM regionsdb.regions
                WHERE IF(calls.destination_number LIKE '1001%', SUBSTRING(calls.destination_number, 5), calls.destination_number) LIKE CONCAT('00', regions.country_prefix, '%')
            )
        )
    )
)
```

**EDIT 2:**
In select "dst" corrected to "destination".

Comment: (1) It is not clear from the `select` clause which table has which fields. Can you provide the table structures, or prefix each field with the table name? (2) What is the primary key of *calls*?

Comment: @trincot the fields are: calls.uid, calls.call_date, calls.destination, regions.name, regions.country_prefix, regions.duration, regions.unit_cost

the primary key of calls is uid.

Comment: Sorry, "duration" belongs to table "calls".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `group by` in combination with `group_concat`, which allows to concatenate a field from the `regions` table in order of descending `country_prefix` length. Then you can extract the first of that.

I will assume that the fields `name`, `unit_cost` are from the `regions` table, if other fields are too, then apply the same logic for them. The `group by` clause should list all the selected fields from the `calls` table, or at least the key fields:

```
select     c.uid, c.call_date, c.dst, 
           substring_index(
                group_concat(r.name order by length(r.country_prefix) desc), 
                ',', 1) as name, 
           substring_index(
                group_concat(r.country_prefix order by length(r.country_prefix) desc), 
                ',', 1) as country_prefix, 
           c.duration,
           substring_index(
                group_concat(format(r.unit_cost, 2) 
                             order by length(r.country_prefix) desc),
                ',', 1) as unit_cost 
from       callsdb.calls c
inner join regionsdb.regions r
        on (left(c.destination_number, 6 + length(r.country_prefix))
              = concat('100100', r.country_prefix)
           or mid(c.destination_number, 3, length(r.country_prefix))
              = r.country_prefix
           )
group by   c.uid,
           c.call_date,
           c.dst,
           c.duration
```

Comment: this looks really promising, thanx! It has half the execution time than my query. But why is "unit_cost" displayed like 0x302E... ??

Comment: OK, that is because `unit_cost` was not cast to string: I edited my answer: use the `format` function.

Comment: Now unit_cost is displayed OK, thanks. The query needs ~14 sec for ~6000 record result. I guess this is the best performance we can get.

Comment: For further improvements I would be looking into triggers that strip that 1001 and 00 upon entry: apparently it serves no purpose. If if does, then it could be written by that trigger in another column.

Comment: Do i have to group by EVERY field of "calls" table i use in query?

Comment: No, at the time I did not know what the key was of `calls`. The key field is enough.

Comment: Even more optimization (half the time) with altering "on" clause: LEFT(IF(LEFT(c.destination, 4) = '1001', SUBSTRING(c.destination, 7), IF(LEFT(c.destination, 2) = '00', SUBSTRING(c.destination, 3), c.destination)), LENGTH(r.country_prefix)) = r.country_prefix